# Using map/ for Each to resolve a web socket message

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a working solution that looks like this.

```
 resolve(stats) {
    object.keys(stats).forEach( key => {
       switch (true) {
         case key === 'PhoneNumber':
             Store.render('tel Number', { PhoneNumber });
             break;
         case key === 'Location':
             getLocation();
             break;
         case key === 'Status':
             getStatus(Status);
             break;
         default:
             break;
     }
 });
}
```

but using switch is messy(?) and it introduces additional cyclomatic complexity. When I try to rewrite it using object literal i just get e huge amount of errors and it just stops working. Currently I'm trying to make it work using variant below,but i still get a mass of errors,because it tries to run every function even though there's no such key present

```
  resolve(stats) {
    object.keys(stats).forEach( key => {
       const keyValue = {
             PhoneNumber: Store.render('tel Number', { PhoneNumber }),
             Location: getLocation(),
             Status: getStatus(Status)
             default: null,
       } 
       return keyValue[key] || keyValue.default;
     })
   }
```

Edit: maybe i need to use array.prototype.reduce? or employ array.some inside the function?

Comment: You should declare your `keyValue` object outside your `forEach` (it doesn't change over iteration).

Comment: Why not `switch (key) { case 'PhoneNumber': /* ... */ break; case 'Location': /* ... */ break; case 'Status': /* ... */ break; default: break }`?

Comment: You wrote `object.keys`. The name of the class is actually `Object` (capital *O*). Also *lots of errors* means nothing unless you post your errors.

Comment: I don't see how you reduce the complexity with your strategy. But what you reduce is readability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to wrap those values into a function like so:

```js
// Dummy function
function getLocation() {
  return '0,0';
}
// Dummy function
function getStatus( status ) {
  return `is: ${ status }`;
}

// Dummy stats
const stats = {
  PhoneNumber: '0012345',
  Location: 'foo',
  Status: 'online',
  SomeOtherStat: 'bar',
};

const mapper = {
  PhoneNumber: ( data ) => {
    //Store.render( data ),
    return data;
  },
  Location: () => getLocation(),
  Status: ( data ) => getStatus( data ),
};

function resolve( stats ) {
  const keys = Object.keys( stats );
  const result = Object.keys( stats ).map( ( key ) => (
    // Check if mapper is available
    mapper[ key ]
      // Run mapper and pass the current value
      ? mapper[ key ]( stats[ key ] )
      // Otherwise return null
      : null
  ) );
  console.log( result );
}

resolve(stats);
```

Otherwise the browser tries to execute it as soon as you create the `keyValue` variable.

Also, you can declare your resolver object outside

Comment: Or just map the names of the methods:
`PhoneNumber: Store.render` etc. Then call them.

Comment: No because then `Store.render` would be called when the `mapper` object is created.

Comment: That makes no sense, why would it be called? If it looks like this:
`const mapper = {  PhoneNumber: Store.render,  Location: getLocation,  Status: getStatus};`

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant it similarly to the to OPs question. You're right, this should work. However, you also might run into errors if e.g. `Store.render` needs the context of `Store`